# How can I upload file by form submit in angular2?

Tags: angular, form-submit

How can I upload file by form submit in angular2. I want to use **ng2-file-upload** library. But I'm not able to use it in form submit. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean with "I'm not able", errors? Did you look up the demo ( http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/ ) ?

Comment: I want to click form submit button and want to submit all data with image/file to backend. How can I do this? @Akkusativobjekt

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible by just passing the uploaded file in your method which can be called in submit.

In your HTML

```
<form #sieFileUploadForm="ngForm">
  <input type="file" id="fileItem" 
  value="Browse...">
```

In you ts

```
uploadFile(file){
 console.log(file)
}
```

> Note:- when sending to beckend you need to make it formdata like this

```
uploadFile(file){
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('FILENAME', file);
}
```

Comment: Actually you just need a input field with the ng2FileSelect directive and a binding to the uploader, eg [uploader]="uploader". An additional button which calls the ulpoad() method and you are done. There is no need to create a FormData object, AFAIK.

Comment: I want to submit others field's data by clicking form submit button.

Comment: Yes u should be able to do that as i mentioned, just pass the data to the method!

Answer (score 0):

So finally I understand your problem, which appears do be additional formdata you want to send with the file.
After you created your `FileUploader`, you can add additional form with the following code :

```
uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: "http://localhost/upload.php" });

  constructor() {
  this.uploader.onBuildItemForm = (item, form) => {
      form.append("key1", "value1");
      form.append("key1", "value2");
    };
}
```

Some say it's a little bit prettier to put this code in the `ngOnInit()`, but I don't want to bloat this code and this decision is not very important here.

Afterwards you can inspect the additional post data in the payload of the http post, for example with the Firefox Developer Tools. They should look like:

```
-----------------------------110224700718602891206418821
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key1"

value1
-----------------------------110224700718602891206418821
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key1"

value2
```

*(Your boundary wont be the same)*

I found the [solution](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/241) on the GitHub tracker of the project.